# How to display X axis from Pandas Dataframe Object to Matplotlib barchart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, graph

I have created a pandas dataframe object from a CSV file being read into a dataframe. The csv is very short and includes the following data:

```
Group Title, Hosts ,Soccer 5, Soccer 4, Soccer 3 , Soccer 2, Soccer 1, Soccer X ,Soccer Y, Soccer Total

Units,11,1,3,4,4,5,

[1 rows x 8 columns]
```

I have successfully displayed the data on a bar chart **however I want the x axis to be labelled for each group title (Hosts, Socker 5, Socker 4 and so on) and plotted in alignment with the data**

Please see a picture of my current graph below to get a better understanding

[image: As you can see the X axis isn't labelled]

I know I can do this manually but I want it to be read from the CSV file i.e the dataframe object. I have tried different methods to do this such as trying to add the following code

```
dataframe.plot.bar(dataframe['Group Title'], title="Soccer", ylabel="Quantity", xlabel="Devices")
```

My full code is below

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib



dataframe = pd.read_csv('C:\Scripts\custom.csv', delimiter=",")

print(dataframe)

dataframe.plot()

#plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (15,8)
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

dataframe.plot.bar(title="Devices", ylabel="Quantity", xlabel="Devices")


#Show Graphs
plt.show()
```

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/)'s [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.barplot(data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image: seaborn barplot]

Alternatively, with pandas only:

```
df.set_index('Group Title').T.plot.bar()
```

[image: pandas barplot]

Comment: Hi when adding the following code: 
dataframe.set_index('Group Title').T.plot.bar() - it throws the error: 

 line 4555, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Group Title'] are in the columns"

Comment: Then just remove the `.set_index('Group Title')` bit. It means that 'Group Title' is already the index in your case, which was not very clear in your question due to formatting.

Comment: Thanks this works. But my key on the top right corner is showing 0 now, instead of hosts, Soccer 5 and so on, any idea how I can get the key to show correctly?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Don't you get the same as me? Can you post an image?

Comment: Yeah sure, so as you can see before I had the following key (please see top right corner of image) but now it just shows the key as 0

https://ibb.co/5M3w8P4

Comment: I see. However this doesn't really make sense. The legend is used to display the groups and here you have only one group as there is a single line of data. If you really need it you have to craft a legend manually (see [plt.legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html))